# Partial const typecast in C++

Tags: c++, struct, casting, constants, partial

Sometimes, when passing or returning structs, it may be needed to make some of the fields const:

```
struct A
{
   char c;
   int x;
};

struct B
{
   const char c;
   int x;
};

void process(B& b)
{
   if(b.c=='1')
      b.x++;
}

void test()
{
   A a;
   a.c = '1';
   a.x = 0;
   process(reinterpret_cast<B&>(a));
}
```

Is this partial const typecasting portable and safe enough?

Comment: We can do something like `process(reinterpret_cast<B&>(const_cast<A&>(a)));` it will work See this http://ideone.com/xnblvi

Answer (score 1):

No such technique is not safe, it is undefined behaviour - casting between unrelated types, even if they look similar, is never safe.

Comment: By 'safe' I mean if X and const X fields always represented in a structure in the same way. They should be, because we can create const pointers to individual fields and compare them to non-const pointers to the same fields, and it is safe. The only unsafe thing about this is the necessity for simultaneous changes in A and B.

Comment: @bkxp Of course you can create pointers to individual fields and compare them. It does not mean that the entire structures are equivalent. (Say, a crazy compiler adds some hidden members before `const` members in debug version for debugging purposes). Nowhere in C++ standard one can find anything supporting such casts. There are few legitimate uses of `reinterpret_cast`, and this is not one of them.

Comment: There are some cases when you might need to restrict writing to certain data members. What approach would you use? Writing an interface class with getters and setters and passing a reference to it, perhaps, to the process() method?

Comment: @bkxp What you suggest is possible. In the example you presented you could even have base class without setter and derived class with it. The `process` function would accept the base class then.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe only for the sample from your code .
In general the technique is not safe.

The a.c isn't constant in the moment of it's declaration , so B.c will inherit the c value , and the constness of c will be use only to enforce syntax.

The problem would occur if the it was the other way around :

```
B b;
b.c = '1';
b.x = '0;
process(reinterpret_cast<A&>(b));
```

The reason would be that b.c would be assigned to a constant at the time of declaration, and attempting to change a.c could result in undefined behavior because you might end up changing a variable from a read only space.

Comment: why that ?? if B is const then we can remove constness by `const_cast`

Comment: You can remove the consteness of an object with const_cast, but if that object is constant at the time of declaration, it might end up in read only memory. A better ilustration is with strings. const char* str = "Hello"; . You can const cast str , but attempting to change anything pointed at str will result in undefined behavior (most likely a crash) if the string "Hello"was placed by the compiler in the read-only memory of the program.

Comment: It is much more obvious with pointers and references. In OP's example there are only values. The op asked about if the technique itself is safe : it is safe for that example only, but in general circumstances with ANY type of variables it is not safe !

Comment: MichaelCMS, compiler will not allow to create B b; without initializing its const fields. Also, it will not allow to assign b.c anything (only initialize it), there will be another compiler error. As for reverse reinterpret_cast, this is similar to creating const int variable and then const_casting it before passing somewhere as int&.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Wojtek.It is not safe clearly because of casting between 2 different types and shouldn't be used.But just for demonstration purposes as i mentioned in comment we can do chaining of typecasting for this particular case.

**1st add constness in A's object and then use reinterpret_cast**

```
struct A
{
   char c;
   int x;
};

struct B
{
   const char c;
   int x;
};

void process(B& b)
{
   if(b.c=='1')
      b.x++;

      cout<<b.x;
}


void  test() {
    // your code goes here
    A a;
   a.c = '1';
   a.x = 3;
   process(reinterpret_cast<B&>(const_cast<A&>(a))); //first add constness to A's data and then use reinterpret_cast

}
```

it is demonstrated here.http://ideone.com/xnblvi If anyone find any problem please comment.

Comment: Adding constness to A makes all of its fields const, and we need the second field non-const, so it will be cast back to non-const with <B&>.

Comment: Is there another way to restrict modification of some struct members without reinterpret_cast? Perhaps, only splitting them into separate arguments, but that's more error prone than the method I mentioned above.

Comment: @bkxp  I am afraid that it will create other problems.The minimum compact solution i found is this one only.